# isinstance() does not detect type for pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to using isinstance() at the beginning of a loop to check the type for each column in a data frame.

I have a lot of columns but isinstance universally fails. For example;

```
test['Total Revenue'].dtypes
```

returns

```
dtype('int64')
```

But using isinstance returns

```
isinstance(test['Total Revenue'].dtypes, (int, np.integer))
False
```

isinstance only recognizes my columns as an object

```
isinstance(test['Total Revenue'].dtypes, object)
True
```

My gut tells me it has something to do with how isinstance is accessing the value, but I'm stuck

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pd.Series.dtypes` returns an instance of the `np.dtype` class, which is also a sub class of `object`. So `isinstance(series.dtypes, int)` will of course fails, but `isinstance(pd.Series([1,2,3]).dtypes,np.dtype)` is `True`.

I think you want

```
test['Total Revenue'].dtypes == 'int64'
```

or

```
pd.Series([1,2,3,]).dtypes == np.int
```

Comment: Just to complement the answer a bit, note (the OP) that it is not the python type that matters here, but what pandas/numpy consider as the "data type". That is why testing with `isinstance` does not make sense. You have to check the **value** of the `dtype` attribute, which is what this answer is teaching you how to do.